# How to get the JSONArray List in RestTemplate Spring

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

1st API response

```
{
    "initial": null,
    "answer": 
    [
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Lion",
            "allowed_values": [
                "2017",
                "2018",
            ],
            "archived": false
        },
        {
        "id": 14,
            "name": "Tiger",
            "allowed_values": [
                "2017",
                "2018",
            ],
            "archived": true
        }

    ],
    "final": null

}
```

2nd API response

```
{
    "initial": null,
    "answer": 
    [
        {
            "date_purchased":null,
            "Tested": true,
            "RollId":12
        },
        {
        "date_purchased":null,
        "Tested": true,
        "RollId":16
        }

    ],
    "final": null

}
```

Demo Class

```
public class Demo {

    String initial;

    Object answer;

    String final;
}
```

My RestTemplate Entity

```
ResponseEntity<Demo> response = restTemplate.exchange(getURL1stAPI, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Demo.class);
```

I can use the answer as Object datatype, but I want to define the answer as a Std class to get more control over it.But the thing is answer can have many different forms as mentioned in the above JSON responses.

```
public class answer_1 {

    Date date;

    String name;

    Set<String> allowed_values;

    String archived;
}

public class answer_2 {

    Date date_purchased;

    String Tested;

    int RollId
}
```

So I can Re-use the same Demo class by providing the datatype of *answer* as either answer_1 or answer_2 when calling the restTemplate.But I couldn't able to figure out how to do this!

Thanks in advance,
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your Demo class like this

```
public class Demo {

    String initial;

    List<Object> answer;

    @JsonProperty("final")
    String finalValue;
}
```

To match both the json's.

1. answer is a array, so you need to declare it as a list.
2. you cannot use final as field name, because final is a keyword. Alternatively, you can create some other field like finalValue, but map the json final to this field using `@JsonProperty`